# diff while ignore unicode whitespace characters (CJK full width space)

Tags: unicode, diff

I'm trying to diff two files. One of these files contains extra full-width spaces (U+3000):

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

```
Text 1
 　 Text 2
Text 3
```

`diff -w A.txt B.txt` reports

```
2c2
< Text 2
---
>  　 Text 2
```

I want to know if there are any options / workarounds so I can get diff by ignore any whitespaces characters (U+3000 Ideographic Space, for example).

Files processed are UTF-8 (with BOM) with CRLF line breaks.

It is fine to use other tools / workarounds if it is not possible with `diff`.

Comment: diff against the output of sed? `<()`

Comment: @TomYan Seems `diff <(cat A.txt | sed 's/\s//g' | sed 's/　//g') <(cat B.txt | sed 's/\s//g' | sed 's/　//g')` works in my case. Though quite ugly...

Comment: First of all you don't need cat. sed can take a file as input, just don't use `-i`. Besides `sed s/\(\s\|　\)//g` should probably work (not sure about portability whatsoever).

Comment: What are settings for locale?

Comment: @RomeoNinov `locale` command says `LANG=C.UTF-8`, `LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"`, ... I hadn't touched that setting before. Should I set locale to something else?